# "ImportError: No module named pynput.keyboard" in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pynput

I have installed python3.8.2 with pip3 version 20.01 and pynput version 1.6.8 is also installed and configured.

OS used is Windows

IDE: PyCharm

launch file on: PyCharm run

```
import pynput.keyboard


def process_key_press(key):
    print(key)


keyboard_listener = pynput.keyboard.Listener(on_press=process_key_press)
with keyboard_listener:
    keyboard_listener.join()
```

**Error**
there is error in:

```
import pynput.keyboard
```

Comment: What error do you get? How have you installed Python and Pynput?

Comment: am using window

Comment: ide is PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1.1 x64

Comment: yes but all in Vain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyCharm creates a new virtual environment for each project by default. You have two choices:

- Select a "System interpreter" for a project, which will use your global environment. See here for more info: [Configure a Python interpreter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-local-python-interpreters.html#)
- Install pynput using pip in the venv using the [terminal embedded](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/terminal-emulator.html) in PyCharm